# How do I display the names of all functions and file names of PHP scripts that are executed during a request to server?

Tags: php

There is, for example, index.php. This file contains the includes/requires of other files with PHP scripts, and there are calls of different functions in them. How do I see the the information about such functions and files(scripts) which are executed during server request?

Comment: Please don't use terms like "for example". Show us what you've done. Don't be vague about "information". What specific information do you want from this? Add more details to your questions. We're not mind readers :)

Comment: You can have a look to `debug_print_backtrace` php function

Comment: I looked it. But it shows nothing...

Comment: I want to see the names of ALL functions, which working in PHP after request to index.php. And I want to see names of all scripts in which such functions (classes) are.